# Some beginner facts on representaions of $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Beginning to learn about representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$. One starts with a subspace $$\mathfrak{h}=\{\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 &a_2& 0\\ 0 & 0 & a_3\\ \end{pmatrix}:\space a_1+a_2+a_3=0\}\subset \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$$ Let $V$ be an arbitrary representation of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_3$. One takes $\alpha\in \mathfrak{h}^*$ and introduces the space $$V_{\alpha}=\{v\in V:\space \forall H\in \mathfrak{h}\space Hv=\alpha(H)v\}$$

The question is why $V=\bigoplus V_{\alpha}$? Could you please explain this phenomenon?

Comment: One reason is that the Jordan Decomposition of elements in a semisimple Lie algebra is preserved under homomorphisms of the Lie algebra (which is essentially what a representation is.) Hence, since elements in $\mathfrak{h}$ have semisimple Jordan Decompositions in the faithful natural three dimensional representation, they act semisimply in all representations. Since they also commute with each other, this means that any finite dimensional representation can be diagonalized with respect to all of $\mathfrak{h}$ simultaneously.

Comment: A very good reference for this type of material is Fulton and Harris: A first course in representation theory. It has the result I stated in the previous comment.

Answer (score 5):

Talking about the case $\dim V<\infty$ only.

Basically this is because the matrices in the spaces $\mathfrak{h}$ commute with each other. Consequently so do the matrices $\alpha(H), H\in\mathfrak{h}$. With a bit more work you can show that those matrices are also semisimple, i.e. diagonalizable. Whenever you have a commuting set of diagonalizable matrices over an algebraically closed field, they are simultaneously diagonalizable. In other words there is a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$ such that all the matrices $\alpha(H)$ are diagonal w.r.t. $\mathcal{B}$.

Obviously the diagonal elements of $\alpha(H)$ are linear combinations of the entries of $H$ (the representation $\alpha$ is a linear mapping). The subspaces $V_\alpha$ are then spanned by subsets of $\mathcal{B}$. The subset includes those basis elements that correspond to the same linear combination, i.e. an element of $\mathfrak{h}^*$.